# jQuery text parser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing, text

Hi **stackoverflow**'ers. I want to create like a text parser with jQuery. What I want is to create a function, in order to pass a string and convert it.

Let's say I have a div with the following HTML code:

```
<div class="item">
    [styled] //The "command" in order to process. If not, return false;
        [code1]Text1[/code1]
        Text2
        [code3]Text3[/code3]
    [/styled]
</div>
```

I want to do this in jQuery

```
$(".item").html(my_decode($(this).html());
```

And change 'div.item' innerHTML to

```
<div class="item">
    <span class="styled">
        <span class="code1">Text1</span>
        Text2
        <span class="code3">Text3</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

As you can see, it checks for [styled], and if it exists, creates a `<span>` with class "styled". And each other [], create a `` `<span> `` with the class of the content.

```
[a]1[/a] [2]a[/2] => <span class="a">1</span> <span class="2">a</span>
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is exactly the question or the problem? where is the function you're creating?

Comment: @Borgtex there is one, took from another site:  http://jsfiddle.net/Vbtrq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you look at an open-source parser such as [Jison](http://zaach.github.com/jison/), and get ideas from it.  Then you can create your own solution and learn a lot from the experience.

Good luck!

Comment: You probably want to use Regular Expressions then.

Comment: Exactly, I was thinking of them but I dont even know how to do one.

Comment: You are just going to have to sit down and spend some time learning regular expressions.  They look horrible to start with, but once you start to get the hang of them they are pretty awesome.  You can check out some tutorials (http://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+regular+expressions+tutorials) or you can buy the brilliant "Mastering Regular Expressions" (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do).  But whatever you do it's going to require some sweat on your part.  Have fun.